# Looking for poem in which sleep is as great an equalizer as death

Tags: poetry, identification-request

There was a poem on the 2015 AP English Literature and Composition exam multiple choice section that I only barely remember. The topic was along the lines of "sleep is as great an equalizer as death" and featured a line like "even the great emperor ... laid his head down to rest."

Does anyone know the title of the poem?

Comment: It's probably not the one you're looking for, but I'm reminded of these lines by Ogden Nash: Stalin and Hitler while they sleep/Are harmless as a baby sheep;/Tyrants who cause the earth to quake/Are only dangerous when awake./This world would be a happier place,/And happier the human race,/And all our pilots be less Pontius,/If people spent more time unconscious.

Comment: [This](https://www.svsd.net/cms/lib/PA01001234/Centricity/Domain/997/IPE_2015_EngLitComp.pdf) seems to be the exam you refer to, but I don't see any poems there that match this description.

Comment: @Alex: That's the practice exam, not the actual paper.

Comment: @GarethRees Isn't it the actual exam that is later used as a practice exam in future years? As far as I know, most practice books for standardized tests give you the actual tests from previous years to practice with.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [*The Shadow Of The Cross*](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/the-shadow-of-the-cross/) by John McCrae?

> At the drowsy dusk when the shadows creep
>   From the golden west, where the sunbeams sleep
>   ...
>   From the attic poor to the palace grand,
>   The King and the beggar went hand in hand.

Answer (score 1):

Not a poem per se, but this is a blank verse passage from Shakespeare's [*Henry IV, Part II*, act 3, scene 1](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=henry4p2&Act=3&Scene=1&Scope=scene), that is often quoted, a testing board favorite, and covers the themes you've mentioned:

> O sleep, O gentle sleep,
>   Nature's soft nurse, how have I frightened thee,
>   That thou no more will weigh my eyelids down,
>   And steep my senses in forgetfulness?
>   Why rather, sleep, liest thou in smoky cribs,
>   Upon uneasy pallets stretching thee,
>   And hush'd with buzzing night-flies to thy slumber,
>   Than in the perfum'd chambers of the great,
>   Under the canopies of costly state,
>   And lull'd with sound of sweetest melody?
>   O thou dull god, why liest thou with the vile
>   In loathsome beds, and leav'st the kingly couch
>   A watch-case or a common 'larum-bell?
>   Wilt thou upon the high and giddy mast
>   Seal up the ship-boy's eyes, and rock his brains
>   In cradle of the rude imperious surge,
>   And in the visitation of the winds,
>   Who take the ruffian billows by the top,
>   Curling their monstrous heads, and hanging them
>   With deafing clamour in the slippery clouds,
>   That with the hurly death itself awakes?
>   Canst thou, O partial sleep, give thy repose
>   To the wet sea-boy in an hour so rude;
>   And in the calmest and most stillest night,
>   With all appliances and means to boot,
>   Deny it to a king? Then, happy low, lie down!
>   Uneasy lies the head that wears a crown.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps John Donne's *Holy Sonnets* 10? Donne explicitly argues that sleep is better than death. He doesn't call sleep an equalizer, but he does say that death is a "slave to ... kings and desperate men", which sleep isn't:

> Death, be not proud, though some have called thee
>   Mighty and dreadful, for thou art not so;
>   For those whom thou think'st thou dost overthrow
>   Die not, poor Death, nor yet canst thou kill me.
>
> From rest and sleep, which but thy pictures be,
>   Much pleasure; then from thee much more must flow,
>   And soonest our best men with thee do go,
>   Rest of their bones, and soul's delivery.
>
> Thou art slave to fate, chance, kings, and desperate men,
>   And dost with poison, war, and sickness dwell,
>   And poppy or charms can make us sleep as well
>   And better than thy stroke; why swell'st thou then?
>
> One short sleep past, we wake eternally
>   And death shall be no more; Death, thou shalt die.

Admittedly this is a long shot, as I'd not expect American teenagers (even those taking AP English) to be able to tackle Donne in an exam setting.